# How to correctly run an exe file on a remote server using ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C#, ASP.NET MVC, and programming in general. Got a task during the internship to write a web application that will let people run scripts with .exe/.lnk extension on a remote server and receive notifications on completion.

I've done research but at the moment completely stuck with the following issue. The task itself creates a lot of technical questions, but I'll try to narrow it down to two:

The button doesn't trigger the controller. For the table creation used https://datatables.net/. Browser doesn't throw any problems while rendering. Also, that code is a cut from an actual table:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#interfaceTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Interface/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "render": function () {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm' onclick= location.href = '@Url.Action("InterfaceRuntime", "Interface")'><i class='fas fa-play-circle'></i> Run</a>";
                    },
            ],
        });
    });
```

If I try to access the controller directly passing an URL(Localhost:~/Interface/interfaceruntime) then the browser throws an exception:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult InterfaceRuntime()
        {

            ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {

                FileName = @"C:\Users\Some.User\Hardcode\Path\to\a\file.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                LoadUserProfile = true,

            };

            Process InterfaceProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                InterfaceProcess.StartInfo = Info;
                InterfaceProcess.Start();
                InterfaceProcess.WaitForExit();
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Executed successfully"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            catch (Exception e)

            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = e });
            }

        }
```

The exception itself:

```
[InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.]
```

It seems that the web request is blocked somewhere else and has nothing in common with the Json request. Would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: First of all *don't* run executables in response to HTTP requests like this. What you're trying to do is essentially a CGI call without results. Returning an *HTTP Success* status for a failed execution isn't a nice idea either. Consider using IIS's CGI support if you *have* to use an external program. IIS will take care of *security*, performance and handling both success and failure responses.

Comment: You just missing `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` after catch `return Json(new { success = false, message = e });`